# Interpreting.Q.w[] for potential problems?

Tags: kdb

From [this page](https://www.kdbfaq.com/how-do-i-interpret-the-output-of-function-q-w/) we know that .Q.w[] gives us for example:

```
used| 108432   / bytes malloced
heap| 67108864 / heap bytes available
peak| 67108864 / heap high-watermark in bytes
wmax| 0        / workspace limit from -w param
mmap| 0        / amount of memory mapped
syms| 537      / number of symbols interned
symw| 15616    / bytes used by 537 symbols
```

If I wanted to monitor the instance for memory issues (eg. memory full) should I be looking at used or heap or a combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to monitor how much is currently being used you would use `used` but it's only a rough estimate of the actual used as it doesn't take into account the memory used by interned strings (symbols) or memory-mapped files.

Monitoring the heap is useful to get a sense of how your memory spikes (and peak gives what the max spike is) but it wouldn't necessarily be ideal for informing you if you're close to your limit because if you have a big memory spike and you hit your limit then the process will die before you have a chance to monitor the fact that the spike was close to the limit.

Ultimately I would monitor both (and peak) and allow yourself buffers in both cases. Have a low-level alert if the heap/peak reaches say 50% of the limit, higher levels at 60%, 70% etc. Then also monitor your used as a percentage of your heap/peak. If your used is a high percentage of your heap - and your heap is a high percentage of your limit - then this could be alarming. Essentially your process could either be:

1. Low-medium memory usage but spiking:

If the used is generally a low-medium percentage of the heap/peak then your process is using low-med memory but spiking. This is pretty harmless and expected if crunching a lot of data

2. used is a high % of heap/peak and heap/peak is a high % of max

Here you might have a situation where a process is storing more and more memory without releasing. So the used is continually growing and the heap/peak is continually growing with it. This is a problem if unchecked.

So essentially you want to capture behaviour 2 while allowing behaviour 1.

There are some other behaviour patterns also but this would be the general gist. Whether or not automatic garbage collect is enabled also plays into it. If auto garbage collect isn't enabled and used is a lot less than heap then this process is hogging memory that it doesn't need to.